# Get all places with more than one tuple of geocoordinates

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I am working with DBPedia data and I am trying to locate all different places with more than one pair of geographic coordinates. It happens sometimes that a place may be referenced as having more than one latitude or longitude. I would like to identify these cases. I have the following query as an example, however the return is counting more than one latitude for cases of places with only one coordinate.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT * WHERE{
    SELECT DISTINCT ?subject (?latitude) (COUNT(?latitude) as ?latitude_counter) (?longitude) (COUNT(?longitude) as ?longitude_counter)
    WHERE {
        ?subject rdfs:label ?label ; a dbpedia-owl:Place.
        ?subject geo:lat ?latitude; geo:long ?longitude.
    }
}
GROUP BY ?subject
HAVING (?latitude_counter > 1)
ORDER BY ?subject
LIMIT 10
```

What is the correct approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are willing to perform the same task, the following query retrieves my result as expected:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT ?subject,
?longitude_counter,
?latitude_counter,
(group_concat(?latitude ; separator = "||") AS ?latitude_set),
(group_concat(?longitude ; separator = "||") AS ?longitude_set)
WHERE
{
    {
        SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE
        {
            SELECT DISTINCT ?subject (COUNT(?latitude) as ?latitude_counter) (COUNT(?longitude) as ?longitude_counter) 
            WHERE 
            {
                ?subject geo:lat ?latitude; geo:long ?longitude .
            }
        } 
    }
    ?subject geo:lat ?latitude; geo:long ?longitude .
    FILTER(?latitude_counter > 1 or ?longitude_counter > 1)
}
ORDER BY DESC(?longitude_counter)
```